Supabase Edge Functions: Importing from npm:
From the supabase docs it shows an example of importing via npm::
e.g.
import React from 'npm:react@18.3.1'
import { Webhook } from 'https://esm.sh/standardwebhooks@1.0.0'
import { Resend } from 'npm:resend@4.0.0'
import { renderAsync } from 'npm:@react-email/components@0.0.22'

see https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions/examples/auth-send-email-hook-react-email-resend
However when I try that in my function, e.g.
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.182.0/http/server.ts";
import {
  IRequestBody,
  sendMail,
} from "https://deno.land/x/sendgrid@0.0.3/mod.ts";
import { getDomain, getEnvironmentVariable } from "../_shared/utils.ts";
import { renderAsync } from "npm:@react-email/render@0.0.7";
import React from "npm:react@18.3.1";

it fails and says:
Failed to load module: "npm:react@18.3.1" - Unsupported scheme "npm" for module "npm:react@18.3.1". Supported schemes: [
    "data",
    "blob",
    "file",
    "http",
    "https",
]
InvalidWorkerCreation: worker boot error

So you cant import via :npm?

fyi current solution i have is to use esm.sh
